# How do I soundproof gaps in sliding windows that I regularly open and close?

Tags: windows, sound-proofing

This is similar to this Q: [Best way to seal gaps in sliding window?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/223569).

But the big difference is that I regularly open and close the sliding windows (at least once a day). (Whereas that other Q is about a once-a-year aircon installation & removal.)

Also, my main goal is to block out/reduce noise from a busy road nearby. (Whereas that other Q is about keeping out insects.)

So, the suggestions in the other Q probably don't work well:

- Foam rubber: Falls out as I open and close the windows. Even if I manage to tape/glue the foam pieces in place (which seems hard for a DIY newbie like me), over time (with opening and closing), the pieces will be torn.
- Spray foam: I haven't tried this yet, but I think similarly, over time, this will be torn.
- Tape: I haven't tried this yet, but I don't think this will do much in reducing noise.

The sliding windows come in three. When they are closed, there are altogether four big gaps--two big gaps between each pair of sliding windows, one upper and one lower.

One such upper big gap:

[image]

One such lower big gap:

[image]

Comment: I forget the name right now, but you want something like fur weatherstripping.  It is made to slide over moving objects.  Unknown how good it is for sound proofing, but probably better than the openings you have.

Comment: My first instinct is some kind of EPDM closed cell foam rubber. The installation strategy is important, though. I would want a low friction material against metal if the plan is to adhesive it to the window frame. I would want a high friction material against metal if the plan is to plug and unplug the holes as a part of the window closing and opening process. Just buy extra and practice a few times on a mock up until you get it right. Glued to the window itself would be far less likely to tear.

Comment: @crip659: Are you thinking of something like this: https://www.amazon.com/Weatherstrip-Soundproofing-Windproof-Dustproof-Stickiness/dp/B08GJ3YCL1?

Comment: That is the weatherstripping I was thinking of.

Comment: Curtains........

Comment: Yep, and depending on the size of the gap, you may want to put the fuzzy weatherstrip on both the frame and the slider.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a two-component solution:  on one of the pair of surfaces, apply a [compressible rubber seal](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/weatherstripping/edge-seals-1%7E/), and on the other, a [low-friction tape](https://www.mcmaster.com/products/low-friction-tape/).  This will facilitate an easy slide with a tight seal, and make it last longer. Both links will give you several variations in form and materials, as well as prices.  You would want to look for something that fits the shape and dimensions of your gaps.

It's unclear to me whether there are also any penetrations in fixed parts; if so, I would plug them with putty or the like.

Another item that may help is [V-seal weather stripping](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082CHZ7RB), a self-adhesive silicon strip with a sort of hinge along its length, available in many lengths from 25 to 45 mm.
You didn't say whether you have reasonable access to the outside of the windows; if so, consider adding treatment there as well.

(None of the links are endorsements.)